# Is the light coming from the CMB redshift?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

I know that using the standard cosmological model you can get a relation of the temperature and redshift

$$T=T_{0}(1+z)$$

and using that formula with $T_{cmb}=3000 K$ and $T_{0}=2.7 K$ you conclude that the redshift of the CMB is $z\approx 1100$.

But there is a way of measuring the redshift of the CMB?

Comment: Why is the redshift of the CMB at decoupling important? To first order it just depends on temperature, which depends on the size of the universe. To get hydrogen recombination requires temperatures of just over 3000 K and therefore the volume of the universe to be about $(3000/2.7)^3$ smaller. This is just thermodynamics, not cosmology.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are efforts to estimate the possible deviations of the measurement, because that is what the measurement is, a fit to black body data. They are using Planck data :

> [We study the capability of Planck data](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255797162_Measuring_the_redshift_dependence_of_the_cosmic_microwave_background_monopole_temperature_with_planck_data) to constrain deviations of the cosmic microwave background (CMB) blackbody temperature from adiabatic evolution using the thermal Sunyaev-Zeldovich anisotropy induced by clusters of galaxies

Again depending on theory.

Comment: Even the spectral measurement of redshift  depends on theories.  That is what measurements are in physics, fitting theories to data   and we call it "measurement" if there is  at least one constraint.

Comment: Well my question is if the measurement is independent of the cosmological model.

For example when you measure the distance of a star you look to the spectroscopic data and with that you can find the redshift of the star(Without assuming a cosmological model). You just look for displacements in absorption lines.

Comment: I know that for measuring the redshift of the star you assume a model for the luminosity of the star, and a lot of other things, but not a cosmological model.

Comment: all this you describe depends on theory , from general relativity to special relativity to atomic  physics to be able to come to a single number

Comment: We fitted a cosmological model from these data.

Comment: I agree with that.You choose a lot of things but not a cosmological model. For example when you meassure the actual temperature of the CMB $T=2.7 K$, you don't have to choose a cosmological model.

Comment: In both cases you utilize the theory of black body radiation. In your question you assume a cosmological model. Without it there is no meaning to the  photon decoupling time.